# Methods for spline fitting for transcendental functions? How to place the knots?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, spline

I was thinking about the following problem the other day:

Fit a spline $s(t)$ to some transcendental function $f(t)$, so that:

$$s(t) = \cases{P_k(t), \text{ if } t_k \leq t \leq t_{k+1}}$$

For polynomials $P_k(t)$:

$$P_k(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} c_{ik}t^i$$

Now we seek $c_{ik}$ so that $s(t)$ approximates $f(t)$ well on interval $t\in [t_0,t_{max}]$.

How can we do this? How to choose the $t_k$ knot points?

Which boundary conditions should be obeyed there?

If the knot points were fixed then the problem could be approached like some least squares norm minimization:

$$\sum_l\|s(t_l)-f(t_l)\|_2^2 + \epsilon(\text{boundary terms})$$

All would be linear. But how to tackle the non-linearity that is introduced with not knowing where knot points should be placed?

Comment: This question was answered in very broad generality by Maurice Cox (1972; 1975), though his formulation was approximating a C^k function, rather than your more specific transcendental. Basically, B-splines are not hurt by equispaced sampling and in fact are somewhat improved. So choose the $t_k$ via uniform sampling. Then the spline of degree $d$ has error of order $\mathcal{O}(h^{d+1})$ with the constant depending on derivatives of $f$; see Kress Numerical Analysis for a friendly introduction.

Comment: Actually $\mathcal C^k$ is also a very interesting case.

Comment: I think splines cannot capture $C^{\infty}$ smoothness, so $C^{k}$ is a natural setting.

Comment: As to boundary conditions: You can do a number of different things. The most common is to use endpoint derivatives to constrain the spline. Another is to just add sample points outside the interpolation domain. The number of extra constraints is proportional to the support of the basis functions $B_{n}$ (cubic splines = linear combs of $B_{3}$ require two extra constraints, quintic splines require 4.)

Comment: In the first sum, shouldn't that t^k be t^i?

Comment: @AntonSherwood yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about convergence, then interpolating splines converge to the initial function if the interpolation step converges towards zero. See for example [here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272427/1-s2.0-S0021904500X03188/1-s2.0-0021904582900740/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHoaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIB3IlytdpbWXHup7x%2B3bFLV2C3r5o3kE9LVkjycJydlcAiBZAZyr2oQ0k3ZrKrqIBWotX0dhkQUvW15kaJIOpLqF7iraAwgzEAIaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMUkL7crpVkkBcjgoMKrcD%2FPSx9ZvNDQpQGSLuD4txfwcJT%2FEGAWx4wROq2SBQW%2FfGv20%2FU4AEic%2F5hWMzOysZJjfrcb0LL5%2BxZrqFR31d911sEJd6dA5WR4CswqxMjtt2bg5HgkvcG78RlGFJTO3TE1FD0TAHyw1O0uUnvgbRpomfBBkVU2poG51zl%2FowJqBXDVZNjQwGhUVeEJOoY8XtCvFqGKegky%2Fp7izQFn2G6vVWDmtwIuXO4c5agjCLx0HD9hjtMrQCh20gZ8oYJhJGfJ1Xkt59A32lX0MhcYfKG2%2BcybhhXUCfBM1xTvGjlfGpmyV157IIxZhzugIXfKLYOoJHl5mFv%2FgF70coj5Sr6GhkzuHpbmdMZFWiKJbd2ObnUKfqpMq2TW%2Bq91QK9Vh9IPed%2BXhVhZM347NUOMzDe%2FRoRqpOFyty11GEU50PUZFNCtACUGi%2FIdN%2B6dRohq7CCe8ViKhvuIAT9A%2FjtQoJIvXi8VkR6ABnYGhXow2Jx3gGwXjCcQ%2FWNyZ3CVa9vS%2Fsr0JJvSakejZf8n3UIcd0hSWza44NkVfFJFVYxc47OctUcX%2Fn2zQ2muuUwrXNR2H1%2FJAQDtDXUjDu6b%2FrBTq1Ad0uoGysRaOBYfmWcL5YCu43zgSeete9Lis6roOoYHgIQ%2FfnuC28cYgvrVJ0dYnYWdb9JeE0H6mJdvjrDrZgw8hI4ixh1WfErdgYAqH1mywMU6ewVeu%2B3iOOtd3tc16tGtJwbI7K6nZm%2BOm4c66uLkr72Q4klPupK7k%2FA6CWzpReiwxRDa8GnBaR5aP7Hb2lI%2FSA8HJ7Qne6MuqpkY9D2ynF1%2Bq5PlWNbUHU2Xd7npl53hJTEqs%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190904T183623Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY2TKU3MDD%2F20190904%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=fbef085e045f00fb4992d68828bf1262b9712a69cf1d1d4e328cd57796b5941a&hash=108ac275d7fe4872e35032ace3aede91e36d37a4839d41b9faf722743ccb59a1&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021904582900740&tid=spdf-31d81c01-abd1-4e9e-a9b0-68ed529505f0&sid=96e58f278c9ec746f389bf54029dcbf3248egxrqb&type=client).